# At what rate does synaptogenesis occur in adults?

Tags: brain, synapses

From many [articles](http://www.oecd.org/education/ceri/31709587.pdf), I can find the rate of synaptogenesis at its highest: roughly 580,000/minute (weeks 6-23 after conception). However, I'm having trouble finding the rate with which it occurs in adults. I find articles stating that it is higher in areas like the hippocampus than other areas and depends on things like exercise and stimulation, but no numbers.

What is the rate of synaptogenesis in a adult brain?

Comment: I did not find the estimate in the cited document (perhaps you confused synaptogenesis with neurogenesis in p. 3?). Anyway, one would need to specify whether that refers to the whole brain or a brain region. I can only provide numbers for mice, if that's useful to you.

Comment: @vkehayas You are right, I did misread the neurogenesis reference on page 3.  The logic will still hold (we start with 0 synapses, and we have N after D days, so N/D synapses per day), but I'll have to adjust the numbers.  Mice numbers would be useful, especially hippocampus and whole brain numbers (from what I understand, the hippocampus  has very high rates of synapse creation compared to others, so that number and the whole brain number would provide useful bounds).